# Django - force default language for sessions, different from MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE

Tags: django, mezzanine

I use Django with Mezzanine. I set languages like that:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"

MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'cs'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('cs', _('Čeština')),
    ('en', _('Angličtina')),
)
```

I do NOT use language in URLs.

The problem is, that default language for new session is selected according browser preferences, however it should be EN allways.

How to achieve that?

I can imagine that it is possible to replace https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/middleware/locale/ with my custom middleware. I guess I should change the function:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    urlconf = getattr(request, 'urlconf', settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
    i18n_patterns_used, prefixed_default_language = is_language_prefix_patterns_used(urlconf)
    language = translation.get_language_from_request(request, check_path=i18n_patterns_used)
    language_from_path = translation.get_language_from_path(request.path_info)
    if not language_from_path and i18n_patterns_used and not prefixed_default_language:
        language = settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
    translation.activate(language)
    request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()
```

Is there a simpler option?

What I should change in the mentioned function to achieve desired behavior?

Answer (score 2):

At the end I figure out that the simplest way is to add my custom middleware:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import translation

class ForceLangMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = "en"
```

This middleware needs to be loaded before the other middlewares.